# CodeBehind not working for ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I want to disable all tooltips in my WPF c# application by a property. I'm using a ResourceDictionary (MyStyle.xaml) for all my Windows, UserControls and so on in this way:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Interface;component/MyStyle.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**This is my ResourceDictionary MyStyle.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="Dupa.Interface.MyStyle">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=TooltipsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>

    ...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

**And the CodeBehind MyStyle.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyStyle : ResourceDictionary, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool tooltipsEnabled;

    public MyStyle()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TooltipsEnabled = false;
    }

    public bool TooltipsEnabled
    {
        get { return tooltipsEnabled; }
        set
        {
            tooltipsEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TooltipsEnabled");
        }
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

---

But the binding is not working. If I set the visibility directly in MyStyle.xaml without binding, it works:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

---

I get some errors during the build:

BindingExpression path error: 'TooltipsEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''CalculationViewModel'
BindingExpression path error: 'TooltipsEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''SettingsViewModel'
BindingExpression path error: 'TooltipsEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''ControllerViewModel'

Comment: Please show us the code for your "BooleanVisibilityConverter". If you intend to use the standard converter, it is called "BooleanToVisibilityConverter", defined in System.Windows.Controls.

Comment: Sorry copy & paste fault. The name of my Converter is BooleanToVisibilityConverter. I'm using it on several places and it works fine. I don't think that the Converter is the problem

Comment: Just saw your edit including the errors. You need to declare the property on all of your ViewModels. Maybe by defining a basic interface that is shared by all viewmodels. The error message seems pretty clear to me. I do not think you can define that in the code behind of a style. Where and especially how do you set the property afterwards anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the errory pretty clearly states, you need to define the property 'TooltipsEnabled' in all of your ViewModels. At the moment you include the Dictionary 'MyStyle' in one of your views, WPF tries to bind that property on your current DataContext, which is most likely the corresponding ViewModel for your Views in which you included the Style.

Personally i would at least define an interface like 'IBaseViewModel' that defines this property, so all of your ViewModels need to implement that property. Creating a base class for that case, from which you derive in your ViewModels is also an option.

Your base class could look something like this:

```
public class BaseViewModel : IBaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool tooltipsEnabled;

    public bool TooltipsEnabled
    {
        get { return tooltipsEnabled; }
        set
        {
            tooltipsEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TooltipsEnabled");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```